# $Metadata with WebAPi OData Attribute Routing Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using OData Attribute Routing for an OData endpoint.  Here is an example of what I have:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Profile")]
public class ProfileODataController : ODataController
{
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var repo = new Repositories.ProfileRepository();

        return Ok(repo.GetProfiles());
    }

    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        var repo = new Repositories.ProfileRepository();

        var result = repo.GetProfiles().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id== key);
        if (result == null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Here is my set up:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", ModelGenerator.GetEdmModel());
```

Here is my EdmModel Generation:

```
public static IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<Profile>("Profile").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

The urls  `/odata/Profile` and `/odata/Profile('someid')` both work, but when I try to access the $metadata endpoint (`/odata/$metadata#Profile`), I get the following error:

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://********/odata/$metadata'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Metadata'."}

Do I need to create a **controller/action** for serving the metadata?  If so, how is that action implemented?

Comment: Can you pls post your `ModelGeneratlr.GetEdmModel()`?

Comment: Nothing special found in your code. There is no need for additional action to serve metadata. You should be able to view metadata using `.../odata/?$metadata` and `.../odata/$metadata`.

Comment: @Blaise As I expect as well, but it's not. I get the same error using either url.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with my replacement of the `IAssembliesResolver`.

I had implemented a custom version to provide only the **component** assemblies that I had implemented controllers in.  However, as the error said, it couldn't find a controller named `MetadataController`.  Turns out, OData implements one: `System.Web.OData.MetadataController`, which provides for the `$metadata` keyword.

Since I had implemented my own `IAssembliesResolver`, the `System.Web.OData` assembly wasn't being included, and `$metadata` failed.  Once I discovered this, and updated my assembly resolver to explicitly include the OData assembly, it now works as it should.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue, thanks for the insight Natha