# OData v4 on .Net Core 1.1 missing /$metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata, .net-core

Using .net Core 1.1, with the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData libraries, I am able to get an OData endpoint working with my simple controller to perform get, $expand, and other queries. However, I can't get it to return the $metadata to be returned. This question ([$Metadata with WebAPi OData Attribute Routing Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772485/metadata-with-webapi-odata-attribute-routing-not-working)) is for the same problem, however the .Net APIs have changed since this was posted.

Is there a setting, flag, or something else I need to enable?

This (http://localhost:52315/odata) seems to return the meta data,

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52315/odata/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Users","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Users"
    },{
      "name":"HelloComplexWorld","kind":"FunctionImport","url":"HelloComplexWorld"
    }
  ]
}
```

this (http://localhost:52315/odata/$metadata) gives me the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NotSupportedException: No action match template '$metadata'
in 'MetadataController'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Conventions.DefaultODataRoutingConvention.SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)
```

My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   app.UseOData("odata");
   app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();
    services.AddSingleton<ISampleService, ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddOData<ISampleService>(builder =>
    {
         builder.Namespace = "Sample";
         builder.EntityType<ApplicationUser>();
         builder.EntityType<Product>();
         builder.Function("HelloComplexWorld").Returns<Permissions>();
    });
}
```

NOTE: I can work around it by adding this at the start of my ConfigureServices(...) method, though it seems wrong given $metadata support should be part of the core platform.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
     if (0 == string.Compare(context.Request.Path, @"/odata/$metadata", true)) {
        context.Request.Path = "/odata";
   }
   await next.Invoke();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I revisited this today and had more success using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.vNext 6.0.2-alpha-rtm package. Referencing [this](https://github.com/kamilhlawiczka/WebApi/tree/aspnetcore/vNext/samples/ODataSample.Web) example, the metadata and default OData routing worked as expected. My minimal configuration is:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOData();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Document>("Documents");

        app.UseMvc(builder =>
        {
            builder.MapODataRoute("odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The */odata/$metadata* route should return "an XML representation of the service’s data model" (EDMX) (according to [the OData v4 Web API documentation](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#02-01-model-builder-abstract)). This is not the same as the service root */odata/*, which returns the top level description of resources published by the OData service (as shown in your example).

I encountered the same issue using the pre-release Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 1.0.0-rtm-00015, since an official release is not yet available ([see open issue on OData Web API repo](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/939)).

To illustrate the point, you could manually emit the metadata, as in the crude example below. (You can find the InMemoryMessage class in the OData/odata.net GitHub repo.)

However, I would suggest waiting for an official release of OData ASP.NET Core as, quoting from the above issue, the "branch is still in its early stages and we may take a different approach once we have our architecture finalized". So things may well change... and $metadata should definitely work "out of the box"!

```
        app.Use((context, func) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/data/v1/$metadata"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var model = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IEdmModel>();

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                InMemoryMessage message = new InMemoryMessage() {Stream = stream};

                ODataMessageWriterSettings settings = new ODataMessageWriterSettings();

                ODataMessageWriter writer = new ODataMessageWriter((IODataResponseMessage)message, settings, model);
                writer.WriteMetadataDocument();

                string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

                return context.Response.WriteAsync(output);
            }

            return func();
        });
```